# Exporting my Tensorflow model and code to a different PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have referred to a number of tutorials and built an object detection model using Faster-RCNN on an Anaconda Virtual Environment. Now I want to show case this model, and find problem when I run it on a different system without Anaconda, I try running it on CMD. In fact, it doesn't run at all.
I have done my research on exporting the model but hit a deadend each time.
I use Anaconda Prompt + Windows 10 + NVidia GPU + Tensorflow-gpu=1.5 to run model on my dedicated system.
I would want to know how can I export this to a different PC which doesn't have the GPU or the Anaconda installed. Or am I completely wrong in the approach and need all the dependencies used when I run it on my system?

Comment: If you are using faster-rcnn from tensorflow object detection API. Then the way to go is to use tensorflow serving

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji Any documentation/tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://medium.com/%40KailaGaurav/deploying-object-detection-model-with-tensorflow-serving-7f12ee59b036&ved=2ahUKEwj6hbe9le3gAhXWWysKHfF2Bj4QjjgwAHoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3RnJ_JoqJ8VB04sDYkr5Iq